# Android: Custom Expandeble List and CheckBox issue. Why is chechbox state random?

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview, baseadapter

Problem is this:

http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/6071/immaginety.png

Why happens that ??
If i check near "Media" and expand node, checkmark goes to second child.
I dont understand why

**EDIT1**: solved checkBox state. Another problem occurs!!

But, maybe i have just understood that the problem isn't checkBox state!!! The problem is the position of rows that switch! If i put an array for checking when a view is just loaded, checkBox state works well! The problem is view position! This is what happens:

```
row0: parentA + checkBoxMARKED

row1: parentB + checkBoxNOTmarked
```

click on A, and this is supposed to happen:

```
row0:      parentA + checkBoxMARKED
 subRow0:  --childA
row1:      parentB + checkBoxNOTmarked
```

but, on the contrary, this occurs (a parent switch)

```
row1:    parentB + checkBoxNOTmarked
 subRow0:  --childA
row0:    parentA + checkBoxMarked
```

Now, if i comment this line

```
if(usedPositionParent.contains(convertView.getId())){

          return convertView;
      }
      else{
          usedPositionParent.add(convertView.getId());
}
```

Situation becomes:

```
row0: parentA + checkBoxMARKED

row1: parentB + checkBoxNOTmarked
```

click on A, and occurs:

```
row1:     parentA + checkBoxNOTmarked
 subRow1: --childA
row0:     parentB + checkBoxMARKED
```

But in reality, parentA is Row 0 !!! So it doesn't appear a checkBox problem. It's a parent position problem!! What are you think about ?

This is new code:

```
public class ListaEspandibileAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter  {

private ArrayList<Object> _objInt;
Context mContext;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

//HashMap<Integer,Boolean> checkboxMap = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
CheckListener checkListner;

ArrayList<Integer> usedPositionParent = new ArrayList<Integer>();

CheckBox checkBox;

public ListaEspandibileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> objList){
    mContext = context;
    _objInt = objList;
    popolaCheckMap();
}   

public void popolaCheckMap(){

    for(int i=0; i< _objInt.size(); i++)
        checkboxMap.put(i, false);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPos, int childPos) {
    return childPos;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPos, int childPos, boolean arg2, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) { 

     if (convertView == null) {
            Log.i("childView", "my parent is "+ groupPos);
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.opportunita_cella_child, null);

            EditText descrizioneEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opportunita_child_descrizione);
            Intervento i = (Intervento) _objInt.get(groupPos);
            descrizioneEditText.setText(i.descrizione);
     }   

     return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
    // i have always one child!
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {

    return _objInt.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPos) {

    return groupPos;
}   

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPos, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


     if(convertView == null) {
            Log.i("parentView", "I'am "+ groupPos);
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.opportunita_cella, null);       
            convertView.setId(groupPos);

            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opportunita_checkbox);          
            checkBox.setFocusable(false); 
            CheckListener checkL = new CheckListener();
            checkL.setPosition(groupPos);
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkL);

            Intervento intervento = (Intervento) _objInt.get(groupPos);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opportunita_image); 
            TextView tipoText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opportunita_tipo); 
            TextView oggettoText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opportunita_oggetto); 
            TextView urgenzaText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opportunita_urgenza); 
            TextView dataText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opportunita_data); 
            TextView oraText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opportunita_ora);    

            if(intervento.getTipo().equals("Guasto"))
                 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_intervento);
            else if(intervento.getTipo().equals("Programmato"))
                 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_programmato);

            tipoText.setText(intervento.tipo);
            oggettoText.setText(intervento.oggetto);

            urgenzaText.setText(intervento.urgenza);
            if(intervento.urgenza.equals("Immediata"))
                 urgenzaText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            else if(intervento.urgenza.equals("Alta"))
                 urgenzaText.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            else if(intervento.urgenza.equals("Media"))
                 urgenzaText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else if(intervento.urgenza.equals("Bassa"))
                 urgenzaText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            Date d = null;
            try {
                 d = sdf.parse(intervento.data);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

            String yyyy = String.valueOf(d.getYear()+1900);

            String MM = String.valueOf(d.getMonth()+1);
            String gg = String.valueOf(d.getDate());
            String hh = String.valueOf(d.getHours());
            String mm = String.valueOf(d.getMinutes());

            if(Integer.parseInt(MM) <= 9)
                 MM = "0"+MM;
            if(Integer.parseInt(gg) <= 9)
                 gg = "0"+gg;
            if(Integer.parseInt(hh) <= 9)
                 hh = "0"+hh;
            if(Integer.parseInt(mm) <= 9)
                 mm = "0"+mm;

            dataText.setText(gg+"-"+MM+"-"+yyyy);
            oraText.setText(hh+":"+mm);
           }

      if(usedPositionParent.contains(convertView.getId())){
          //checkBox.setChecked(checkboxMap.get(groupPos));
          return convertView;
      }
      else{
          usedPositionParent.add(convertView.getId());
      }              

         //if(isExpanded)
            // checkBox.setChecked(checkboxMap.get(groupPos));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return false;
}

public class CheckListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

    int pos;

    public void setPosition(int p){
        pos = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        Log.i("checkListenerChanged", String.valueOf(pos)+":"+String.valueOf(isChecked));
        //checkboxMap.put(pos, isChecked);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to view recycling. Are you using the convert view in getGroupView?

Make sure some things

- That you save the state of the checkboxes when checked and set the value in getGroupView.
- That you implement getGroupId() and getChildId() to have unique and stable ids per group (child id is unique within the group).
- Preferably override hasStableIds() and set to true if you can promise stable ids.

Note that recycling in ExpandableListView is a bit strange and could need some extra work from your part. From the documentation:

> *convertView* the old view to reuse, if possible. You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If
>   it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data,
>   this method can create a new view. It is not guaranteed that the
>   convertView will have been previously created by getGroupView(int,
>   boolean, View, ViewGroup).

Comment: Yes i am. So do i have to save each checkBox state in a separate array, for example, and set 'setChecked' in groupview? Could you give me a example? You have to consider the fact that, when list is loaded, check state is always 'false'. Then i can check it to true and, for each 'true' i've found, i save that row in my db.

Comment: Yes. That is probably the simplest way if you only want to save it in memory.
1. Set an OnCheckedChangedListener when inflating.
2. Always set the referenced row id on the checkbox in as a tag when binding.
3. Set the checked state in for example an SparseBooleanArray when a check event occurs using the id you saved as a tag on the checkbox.
4. CaLl setChecked in bindView using the value from the SparseBooleanArray.
There is also a concept of choice mode multiple, but it wont work with expandable listview afaik.

Comment: Nothing! I can't do that. It's a little hard :/

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
     ArrayList<Boolean> item_checked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
     in starting item_checked.add(false)


     holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (isChecked)
                  {
                      itemChecked.set(position, true);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      itemChecked.set(position, false);
                  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Nothing Kubi! Problem still occurs.